# How to use predefined lowercase-letters after the year (e. g. 1990f [1969]) in the bibliography with correct order

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I want to use the "official" lowercase-letters from the collected works of one author (e. g. 1990f [1969]) in my text and bibliography, even if I don't cite all the other titles of the same year (1990a, 1990b etc.).

But if I change the year directly in my bibtex-entry, I get a wrong order in the bibliography. Is there a way to fix this (even with another year in square brackets that shows when a posthumous published title was originally written)?

And by the way, but less important, if I use the official abreviation for the title (e. g. 1990), but the collected works edition is from a different year (e. g. 1999), how can I implement that in the bibtex-entry (my solution, to put that year under "edition" is bad).

Would be so great if somebody finds a solution, couldn't find a similar question.

[image]

Here is a minimal working example

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[natbib=true,backend=biber,
style=ext-authoryear-iecomp]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{example.bib}
@InCollection{Fromm.1947a,
  author    = {Erich Fromm},
  booktitle = {Erich Fromm Gesamtausgabe},
  title     = {Psychoanalyse und Ethik},
  year      = {1947a},
  address   = {Stuttgart},
  edition   = {1999},
  editor    = {Rainer Funk},
  pages     = {1-158},
  volume    = {II},
}

@InCollection{Fromm.1955a,
  author    = {Erich Fromm},
  title     = {Wege aus einer kranken Gesellschaft},
  booktitle = {Erich Fromm Gesamtausgabe},
  year      = {1955a},
  editor    = {Rainer Funk},
  volume    = {IV},
  pages     = {1-254},
  address   = {Stuttgart},
  edition   = {1999},
}

@InCollection{Fromm.1990f,
  author    = {Erich Fromm},
  booktitle = {Erich Fromm Gesamtausgabe},
  title     = {Die dialektische Revision der Psychoanalyse},
  year      = {1990f [1969]},
  address   = {Stuttgart},
  edition   = {1999},
  editor    = {Rainer Funk},
  pages     = {19-72},
  volume    = {XII},
}

@InCollection{Fromm.1991d,
  author    = {Erich Fromm},
  booktitle = {Erich Fromm Gesamtausgabe},
  title     = {Die dialektische Revision der Psychoanalyse},
  year      = {1991d [1974]},
  address   = {Stuttgart},
  edition   = {1999},
  editor    = {Rainer Funk},
  pages     = {237-258},
  volume    = {XII},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{example.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{Fromm.1947a} \cite{Fromm.1955a} \cite{Fromm.1990f} \cite{Fromm.1991d}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

edit Appendix: Assume that I have another bibresource that should work normal and autogenerate the extradate. Is there a way to have the only predefined extradates in my example.bib but not in my citavi.bib?

```
\begin{filecontents}{citavi.bib}
@article{Hacker-Wright.2009a,
 author = {Hacker-Wright, John},
 year = {2009},
 title = {What is Natural About Foots Ethical Naturalism?},
 pages = {308--321},
 volume = {22},
 number = {3},
 journal = {Ration (New Series)}
}
@article{Hacker-Wright.2009b,
 author = {Hacker-Wright, John},
 year = {2009},
 title = {Human Nature, Personhood, and Ethical Naturalism},
 pages = {413--427},
 volume = {84},
 number = {3},
 journal = {Philosophy}
}
@article{Lott.2012,
 author = {Lott, Micah},
 year = {2012},
 title = {Have Elephant Seals Refuted Aristotle? Nature, Function, and Moral Goodness},
 pages = {353--375},
 volume = {9},
 number = {3},
 journal = {Journal of Moral Philosophy},
}
@article{Lott.2012b,
 author = {Lott, Micah},
 year = {2012},
 title = {Moral Virtue as Knowledge of Human Form},
 pages = {407--431},
 volume = {38},
 number = {3},
 journal = {Social Theory and Practice},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{example.bib} %(or: \addbibresource{\jobresource.bib})
\addbibresource{citavi.bib}
\begin{document}
\autocite{Fromm.1947a}
\autocite{Fromm.1955a}
\autocite{Fromm.1990f}
\autocite{Fromm.1991d}
\autocite{Hacker-Wright.2009a}
\autocite{Hacker-Wright.2009b}
\autocite{Lott.2012,Lott.2012b}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

edit 2: and what happens if there are more publications with the same year actually cited? e. g. the following entries:

```
@InCollection{Fromm.1955b,
  author            = {Erich Fromm},
  booktitle         = {Erich Fromm Gesamtausgabe},
  title             = {Die Auswirkungen eines triebtheoretischen \frqq Radikalismus\flqq\ auf den Menschen. Eine Antwort auf Herbert Marcuse},
  year              = {1955},
  officialextradate = {2},
  editor            = {Rainer Funk}, 
  editiondate       = {1999},
  volume            = {VIII},
  address           = {Stuttgart},
  publisher         = {DVA},     
  pages             = {113-120},
  options           = {officialextradate,labeldateparts=false},
}
@InCollection{Fromm.1955c,
  author            = {Erich Fromm},
  booktitle         = {Erich Fromm Gesamtausgabe},
  title             = {Eine Erwiderung auf Herbert Marcuse},
  year              = {1955},
  officialextradate = {3},
  editor            = {Rainer Funk}, 
  editiondate       = {1999},
  volume            = {VII},
  address           = {Stuttgart},
  publisher         = {DVA},     
  pages             = {123-124},
  options           = {officialextradate,labeldateparts=false},
}

\autocite{Fromm.1955a,Fromm.1955b,Fromm.1955c}
```

Comment: In what sense “1990f” is “official”?

Comment: It's, at least in Germany, academic practice if all works of an author are listed in the collected works with specific letters in the correct order to use them (look for example at this publication: https://opus4.kobv.de/opus4-Fromm/files/9979/Funk_R_1996e.pdf )

Comment: In general that is not the case in Germany, maybe some people do it in your field, but that's hardly official

Comment: at least it is a common practice when people cite the "Erich Fromm Gesamtausgabe", but of course people don't cite it in every field. This is also true for the citations of the Works of Freud (https://www.klett-cotta.de/media/35/ZS_PS_Hinweise_fuer_Autoren.pdf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have never seen citations using an official `extradate` letter before (I have only ever seen documents where the disambiguating `extradate` letter was calculated based on the works cited in the specific bibliography), but here is a way to achieve this.

First of all, you'll need to make your input more machine readable. I decided to split

```
  year      = {1990f [1969]},
  edition   = {1999},
```

into the components

```
  year              = {1990},
  officialextradate = {6},
  origyear          = {1969},
  editiondate       = {1999},
  options           = {officialextradate,labeldateparts=false},
```

of which `officialextradate` and `editiondate` are new fields that we will need to declare with a `.dbx` data model.

The two options `officialextradate,labeldateparts=false` are required for all entries that are cited with an 'official' `extradate` letter. The options tell Biber to disregard the entries for `extradate` calculation and tell our code to use the `officialextradate` instead.

If the `officialextradate` option is set, we simply inject `officialextradate` for `extradate`. Since we had to completely disable `labelyear` calculation for that, we get it back by defining `labeldatesource` and slightly mess with some internals to get back the behaviour as if we hadn't set `labeldateparts=false`. We also sort by `officialextradate` information if available. Then it is just a matter of making sure printing `origdate` and `editiondate` in the appropriate cases. Everything else can be handled by `biblatex` with the facilities that are already present.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{filecontents}{moredates.dbx}
\ProvidesFile{moredates.dbx}[2020/12/13 more dates for biblatex]

\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field, datatype=integer]{
  officialextradate}

\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field, datatype=date, skipout]{
  editiondate}

\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{
  officialextradate,
  editionday,
  editionendday,
  editionendhour,
  editionendminute,
  editionendmonth,
  editionendseason,
  editionendsecond,
  editionendtimezone,
  editionendyear,
  editionhour,
  editionminute,
  editionmonth,
  editionseason,
  editionsecond,
  editiontimezone,
  editionyear,
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[natbib=true,backend=biber, datamodel=moredates,
  style=ext-authoryear-iecomp]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newtoggle{bbx:officialextradate}
\DeclareEntryOption[boolean]{officialextradate}[true]{%
  \settoggle{bbx:officialextradate}{#1}}

% get rid of the extradate calculated by Biber
% and inject officialextradate as extradate
\makeatletter
\AtDataInput{%
  \iftoggle{bbx:officialextradate}
    {\csxappto\blx@bbl@data{%
       \def\noexpand\abx@field@labeldatesource{}%
       \let\expandafter\noexpand\csname abx@field@extradate\endcsname
         \expandafter\noexpand\csname abx@field@officialextradate\endcsname}}
    {}%
}

\def\blx@imc@iflabeldateisdate{%
  \iffieldundef{labeldatesource}
    {\@secondoftwo}
    {\iffieldequalstr{labeldatesource}{}
       {\@firstoftwo}
       {\iffieldequalstr{labeldatesource}{year}}}}
\makeatother

\DeclareFieldFormat{origdate}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}

\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{date+extradate}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[\blx@delimcontext labeldate]{%
       \iflabeldateisdate
         {\printdateextra}
         {\printlabeldateextra}%
       \setunit*{\addspace}%
       \printorigdate}}}
\makeatother

\renewbibmacro*{date}{%
  \usebibmacro{bbx:ifmergeddate}
    {\printeditiondate}
    {\printdate}}

\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
  \ifboolexpr{test {\usebibmacro{bbx:ifmergeddate}}
              and test {\iffieldundef{editionyear}}
              and test {\iffieldundef{issue}}}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
       \printfield{issue}%
       \setunit*{\addspace}%
       \usebibmacro{bbx:ifmergeddate}
         {\printeditiondate}
         {\printdate}}}%
  \newunit}

\DeclareLabeldate{%
  \field{date}
  \field{year}
  \field{eventdate}
  \field{urldate}
  \literal{nodate}
}

\DeclareSortingTemplate{nyt}{
  \sort{
    \field{presort}
  }
  \sort[final]{
    \field{sortkey}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortname}
    \field{author}
    \field{editor}
    \field{translator}
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortyear}
    \field{year}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{officialextradate}
    \literal{9999}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{volume}
    \literal{0}
  }
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@InCollection{Fromm.1947a,
  author            = {Erich Fromm},
  booktitle         = {Erich Fromm Gesamtausgabe},
  title             = {Psychoanalyse und Ethik},
  year              = {1947},
  officialextradate = {1},
  address           = {Stuttgart},
  editiondate       = {1999},
  editor            = {Rainer Funk},
  pages             = {1-158},
  volume            = {II},
  options           = {officialextradate,labeldateparts=false},
}
@InCollection{Fromm.1955a,
  author            = {Erich Fromm},
  title             = {Wege aus einer kranken Gesellschaft},
  booktitle         = {Erich Fromm Gesamtausgabe},
  year              = {1955},
  officialextradate = {1},
  editor            = {Rainer Funk},
  volume            = {IV},
  pages             = {1-254},
  address           = {Stuttgart},
  editiondate       = {1999},
  options           = {officialextradate,labeldateparts=false},
}
@InCollection{Fromm.1990f,
  author            = {Erich Fromm},
  booktitle         = {Erich Fromm Gesamtausgabe},
  title             = {Die dialektische Revision der Psychoanalyse},
  year              = {1990},
  officialextradate = {6},
  origyear          = {1969},
  address           = {Stuttgart},
  editiondate       = {1999},
  editor            = {Rainer Funk},      
  pages             = {19-72},
  volume            = {XII},
  options           = {officialextradate,labeldateparts=false},
}
@InCollection{Fromm.1991d,
  author            = {Erich Fromm},
  booktitle         = {Erich Fromm Gesamtausgabe},
  title             = {Die dialektische Revision der Psychoanalyse},
  year              = {1991},
  officialextradate = {4},
  origyear          = {1974},
  address           = {Stuttgart},
  editiondate       = {1999},
  editor            = {Rainer Funk},
  pages             = {237-258},
  volume            = {XII},
  options           = {officialextradate,labeldateparts=false},
}
@article{Hacker-Wright.2009a,
  author  = {Hacker-Wright, John},
  year    = {2009},
  title   = {What is Natural About Foots Ethical Naturalism?},
  pages   = {308--321},
  volume  = {22},
  number  = {3},
  journal = {Ration (New Series)},
}
@article{Hacker-Wright.2009b,
  author  = {Hacker-Wright, John},
  year    = {2009},
  title   = {Human Nature, Personhood, and Ethical Naturalism},
  pages   = {413--427},
  volume  = {84},
  number  = {3},
  journal = {Philosophy},
}
@article{Lott.2012,
  author  = {Lott, Micah},
  year    = {2012},
  title   = {Have Elephant Seals Refuted Aristotle?
             Nature, Function, and Moral Goodness},
  pages   = {353--375},
  volume  = {9},
  number  = {3},
  journal = {Journal of Moral Philosophy},
}
@article{Lott.2012b,
  author  = {Lott, Micah},
  year    = {2012},
  title   = {Moral Virtue as Knowledge of Human Form},
  pages   = {407--431},
  volume  = {38},
  number  = {3},
  journal = {Social Theory and Practice},
}
@InCollection{Fromm.1955b,
  author            = {Erich Fromm},
  booktitle         = {Erich Fromm Gesamtausgabe},
  title             = {Die Auswirkungen eines triebtheoretischen
                       \frqq Radikalismus\flqq\ auf den Menschen.
                       Eine Antwort auf Herbert Marcuse},
  year              = {1955},
  officialextradate = {2},
  editor            = {Rainer Funk}, 
  editiondate       = {1999},
  volume            = {VIII},
  address           = {Stuttgart},
  publisher         = {DVA},     
  pages             = {113-120},
  options           = {officialextradate,labeldateparts=false},
}
@InCollection{Fromm.1955c,
  author            = {Erich Fromm},
  booktitle         = {Erich Fromm Gesamtausgabe},
  title             = {Eine Erwiderung auf Herbert Marcuse},
  year              = {1955},
  officialextradate = {3},
  editor            = {Rainer Funk}, 
  editiondate       = {1999},
  volume            = {VII},
  address           = {Stuttgart},
  publisher         = {DVA},     
  pages             = {123-124},
  options           = {officialextradate,labeldateparts=false},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\autocite{Fromm.1947a}
\autocite{Fromm.1955a}
\autocite{Fromm.1990f}
\autocite{Fromm.1991d}

\autocite{Hacker-Wright.2009a}
\autocite{Hacker-Wright.2009b}
\autocite{Lott.2012,Lott.2012b}

\autocite{Fromm.1955a,Fromm.1955b,Fromm.1955c}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Fromm, Erich (1947a). „Psychoanalyse und Ethik“. In: Erich Fromm Gesamtausgabe. Hrsg. von Rainer Funk. Bd. II. Stuttgart, 1999, S. 1–158.]

Comment: Thank you so much! Unfortunately this doesn’t work so well with my other bibresource that is citavi-generated and should autogenerate the extradate… I get an error when I cite two or more titles with the same year (e. g. \cite{author.1999,author.1999b}) or the extradate is missing if I don’t define an officialextradate. Is there possibly a way that these changes only concern my extra-bibresource for these special cases, where the extraletter should be predefined, and not my citavi-bibresource, where the extraletter should be autogenerated? (I edited the question and added an example)

Comment: @Horstfuchs This makes things a bit trickier. See the edit, please.

Comment: Oh wow, it works amazing, thank you so much for your help! That's really a help

Comment: ah, now I notice one problem that is still remaining: somehow the editiondate disappears and is replaced by the year of publication... how does that come?

Comment: and somehow the sorting of publications with the same year doesn't work correctly (I appended some more publications in the example.bib in the original entry). Hm, this seems to be harder then expected..

Comment: @Horstfuchs And again...

Comment: oh thank you very much, now it works!